# Modal to show once per session

Tags: javascript

Have created a cookie modal about cookies but I want to make it possible when an user closes the cookies popup it won't show them only if they delete caches from their own browser.
Did some attempts to try from my own with localStorage but as a beginner in JavaScript didn't had success and looking for anyone here to help me do that.
p.s: There were so many posts there asking for help how to make a popup show only once, but all of them were with jQuery and i'm using Vanilla JavaScript.

```js
let cokies = document.querySelector('.kokies');
let closeBtn = document.querySelector('.kokie-btn');

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);

function closeModal () {
    document.querySelector('.kokies').style.display = 'none'; 
}
setTimeout( function() {
    document.querySelector('.kokies').style.display = 'block';
}, 4200);
```

```css
body{
background: red;
.kokies{
  max-height: 130px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: coral;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
.info{
  background-color: #BAE107;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 270px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: black;
}
.kokie-btn{
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 70%;
  top: 28%;
  width: 76px;
  height: 39px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 750;
  background-color: #4CD398;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.kokie-btn:hover{
  background-color: #30B279;
}
```

```html
         <div class="kokies">
           <span class="info">This website uses cookies to ensure you get the best experience on our website</span> 
           <button class="kokie-btn" type="button">Got it!</button>
         </div>
```

Comment: You could use a persistent cookie since they already said OK to cookies.

Comment: or on second thought a session cookie in case it's a shared computer.  Either way setcookie ( has-seen-cookie-alert ) then there's no need for local storage.